# Escaping a forward slash in an SQL name? It can be "escaped", but SQL believes it to be multiple columns

Tags: mysql

The last person in my job has flooded column names with special characters such as (?,!, and /), as well as used many reserved keywords for column names (more often than not, timestamp or user is used).

Normally, I step around this by using double quotes or brackets to escape the SQL object.  A subset of the full list of columns are below:

```
DriverID, 
Department, 
Odometer, 
MerchantState, 
MerchantCity, 
gallons/Units, 
timestamp, 
tax
```

Inside my query, I wrap the two columns in question (gallons/units and timestamp) inside double quotes.  Timestamp because it's a reserved keyword, and Gallons/units, because without the quotes, SQL reads the query, stops at the slash, and tells me "Gallons" is not a column inside the table.

If I do wrap double quotes around the column name, SQL returns a different error: "Operand should contain 1 column(s)".

I've tried every variant (only capturing the slash in quotes, quoting both, using brackets, mixing brackets and quotes, etc. but with to no avail).

Is there anything I can do to fix this query short of renaming the column name and changing the associated code in the program that pulls from it? (the really tedious task I'm trying to avoid).

Comment: Can you remove one of either mysql or sql-server tags, please?

Comment: What are you actually using?  `Sql Server` or `Mysql`?  For SQL Server, you should use `[]` around the columns, and for Mysql you should use back-ticks.

Comment: neither timestamp nor user are reserved words !?!?

Comment: Also, can you confirm your RDBMS - and I really think fixing the schema is the right way to go.

Comment: I removed the sql-server tag.  Additionally, back-ticks do the same thing as double quotes in my scenario.  Gallons/Units get's escaped, but MySQL still says, what whatever reason, that the operand should contain only 1 column(s)

Answer (score 4):

In SQL Server, identifiers can be delimited using square brackets, e.g.

```
SELECT [gallons/units] ...
```

In MySQL, identifiers can be delimited using backticks, e.g.

```
SELECT `gallons/units` ...
```

(NOTE: If MySQL `SQL_MODE` includes `ANSI_QUOTES`, then double quotes are treated as delimiters for identifiers, similar to the way Oracle handles double quotes; absent that setting, double quotes are handled as delimiters for string literals. With `ANSI_QUOTES` included `SQL_MODE`, `"gallons/units"` will be interpreted as an identifier (column name). Without `ANSI_QUOTES`, MySQL will see it as a string literal, as if it were enclosed in single quotes.)

---

FOLLOWUP:

As far as an error `"operand should contain only 1 column(s)"`, that's usually a problem with query semantics, not an issue with escaping identifiers.

A subquery in the SELECT list can return only a single expression, for example, this would throw an error:

```
Query: SELECT 'foo' , ( SELECT 'fee' AS fee, 'fi' AS fi )

Error Code: 1241
Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try backticks instead of double quotes

```
 `gallons/units`
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of options.  First, have you tried using %/ to escape the slash?

Example:  "select * from 'gallons%/units';"

Second one I've found, which may or may not be helpful, is to provide an escape character definition, such as 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainala/archive/2008/08/17/using-and-escape-clause-in-sql-server-like-query.aspx

> select * from MyTable where Description like '|[summary|]%' escape '|'

In your case
    select * from 'gallons|/units' escape '|'

You indicate both mysql and sql-server in your tags, so I'm not sure which server support I should be looking for exactly.

Comment: The `ESCAPE` clause is only valid with a `LIKE` operator. It's not valid in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: spencer is correct and it looks like his answer is the one you're looking for.  Kudos.