# C# Can't figure out what's wrong with my MySql command string (syntax error)

Tags: c#, mysql, exception, syntax-error

I'm using the MySql.Data library for accessing my MySql database and I'm encountering some difficulty with entering a row into one of my tables. Could someone please inspect what I've provided here and point out what's wrong?

Here are the column names in my MySql database exactly:

```
ID
Full Name
Date of Birth
City
State/Province/Region
Zip Code
Country
Phone Number
Email Address
Ticket Number
Registration Time
```

Here is my command string (it becomes complete when I use string.Format to use parameters from a function as values):

```
string commandString = "INSERT INTO Participants (ID,Full_Name,Date_of_Birth,City,State/Province/Region,Zip_Code,Country,Phone_Number,Email_Address,Ticket_Number,Registration_Time) VALUES ('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}','{7}','{8}','{9}','{10}');";
```

Here is the exception message:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near
>   ''State/Province/Region',Zip_Code,Country,Phone_Number,Email_Address,Ticket_Numbe'
>   at line 1

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why did you name a column `State/Province/Region`?  What's probably happening is you are getting an apostrophe within one of your columns.

Comment: ``State/Province/Region`` use backticks (ALT+096)

Answer (score -1):

Try escaping the name of your `State/Province/Region` column by surrounding it in back ticks (`). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27783264/escaping-a-forward-slash-in-an-sql-name-it-can-be-escaped-but-sql-believes-i) for more info.

Also, you are trying to store a formatted string without calling `String.Format`.

Try something like this:

```
string commandString = String.Format("INSERT INTO Participants (ID,Full_Name,Date_of_Birth,City,`State/Province/Region`,Zip_Code,Country,Phone_Number,Email_Address,Ticket_Number,Registration_Time) VALUES ('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}','{7}','{8}','{9}','{10}');",
                                     value0, value1, value2, value3, value4, value5, value6, value7, value8, value9, value10);
```

Just replace the `value0`, `value1`, etc variables to your values.

Comment: This is mysql, not ms sql or ms access.